# Adding a row to a dataset is not updating the database (C#)

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, dataset

A very simple, yet very frustrating issue. I've bound a datagrid to a local database so as to play around and teach myself about datasets and c#. Binding the data, no problem. Custom fills (and sql selects), no problem. Next comes adding a record. So, I add in the following code:

```
private void bAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow newRow = abbtestDataSet.Tables["main"].NewRow();
            newRow["Name"] = "Simon";
            newRow["Age"] = 23;
            abbtestDataSet.Tables["main"].Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
```

The datagrid updates no problem, however the data is never actually committed to the database. I've searched high and low for a solution or something I may be missing out on and nothing; at least from what I've seen I'm doing everything right.

So what am I missing? Undoubtedly something very stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use a `DataAdapter` to actually send the updated `DataSet` to the database.

Check out the links below for more info:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/UseDataTabletoinsertaRow.htm

[Using ADO.NET for beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners)

The relevant sample from the first link is:

```
    string ConnectionString ="server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY ID", conn);

    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

    // Create a dataset object
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("EmployeeSet");
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Employee");

    // Create a data table object and add a new row
    DataTable EmployeeTable = ds.Tables["Employee"];
    DataRow row = EmployeeTable.NewRow();
    row["FirstName"] = "R";
    row["LastName"] = "D";
    row["ID"] = "10";
    EmployeeTable.Rows.Add(row);

    // Update data adapter
    adapter.Update(ds, "Employee");
```